# Spring Sequrity login and session management

Tags: spring-security

I`m creating a Rest application that will have the login/logout/register functionalities   and I`m at the point that I need to handle the login and the session

I`m using Spring security for this( and is the first time I had interaction with this big framework)

I want to ask, what is the best way to handle the session in order to be stateful

I`m thinking of an object in memory that keep the track of some tokens
also, I want to have spring security take the credentials from the header instead of the body of the request

can someone give some useful advice regarding the session management and for the credentials how it will be passed from my Client service?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Authentication and session management are big topics and I'm afraid that your question is too broad.

But you can start reading the Spring Security Reference in the [Username/Password Authentication section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-unpwd) and the [Session Management section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#session-mgmt).

By default, Spring Security will manage the session by persisting it in the `HttpSession` of the embedded tomcat (in the case of Spring Boot).